# Stop Button Causing ListBox to Deselect

Tags: c#, wpf, button, listbox

I have a button in place so that when I click it, it deletes the selected `ListItem` from the `ListBox` called `listBoxNames` and removes the selected `Person` object from a list named `people`.

However, after clicking the delete button an error message pops up telling me that the index is out of range. This leads me to believe that upon clicking the button, it has deselected the `ListBox` and so `listBoxNames.SelectedIndex` returns -1.

Is there anyway around this or have I made some stupid mistake?

```
private void deleteEntryBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
    {
        try
        {
            listBoxNames.Items.Remove(listBoxNames.SelectedItems[0]);
            people.RemoveAt(listBoxNames.SelectedIndex);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code removes the selected item.
Once that item isn't there, there is no selection.

You need to check which item is selected before removing it.

Comment: *face palm* - reversing the order of the code should suffice.

Answer (score -1):

Try this instead:

```
private void deleteEntryBtn_Click(object sender, RoutedEventArgs e)
{
    try
    {
        people.RemoveAt(listBoxNames.SelectedIndex);
        listBoxNames.RemoveAt(listBoxNames.SelectedIndex);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        MessageBox.Show(ex.Message);
    }
}
```